# can we add system icons into the flex application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

can i add system icons (.doc, .ppt icons etc) into my flex application without embedding them into the application directly.

Comment: Remember that this would depend highly on whether the system has those icons installed or not, which might not be what you want.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're trying to make an AIR application and you want to use the system's icons for .doc, .ppt, etc files.

This is possible!
Check out the link...

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/File.html#icon

This won't work on Linux as far as i can recall...

Cheers

Comment: The app will need a fall back anyway in the event the Mac/Windows users doesn't have an application installed to handle that filetype.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but for that u need to know the path in which the icons are installed and your application should have access to it.

Thanks,

Nirmal